# Why does the table keep having 4 results of the same book in question 65 Chapter 8 of Database?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    BOOK_NUM,
    BOOK_TITLE,
    BOOK_SUBJECT,
    ROUND(AVGCOST, 2) AS 'Average Subject Cost',
    BOOK_COST - ROUND(AVGCOST, 2) AS DIFFERENCE
FROM
    BOOK
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        BOOK_SUBJECT AS s, AVG(BOOK_COST) AS AVGCOST
    FROM
        BOOK
    GROUP BY BOOK_NUM) AS S;
```

Comment: you are missing a on Clause, that join the tables at only the choosen point

Comment: What book? what question? BTW no ones going to reference the book you should include everything that the reader needs to know in the question please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a cross join, getting all possible pairs of BOOK records and records returned from your S subquery.  Presumably you intended to do an inner join, adding an ON clause after `AS S`, something like `ON S.s=BOOK.BOOK_SUBJECT`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare a ON clause to define where you want to join both tables.
Check the result and then see if you have to adept  the ON clause

```
SELECT 
    BOOK_NUM,
    BOOK_TITLE,
    BOOK_SUBJECT,
    ROUND(AVGCOST, 2) AS 'Average Subject Cost',
    BOOK_COST - ROUND(AVGCOST, 2) AS DIFFERENCE
FROM
    BOOK b
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        BOOK_SUBJECT AS s, AVG(BOOK_COST) AS AVGCOST
    FROM
        BOOK
    GROUP BY BOOK_NUM) AS S
    ON b.BOOK_SUBJECT = s.s AND b.BOOK_COST = s.AVGCOST;
```